# Solve $x^5=\frac{133x-78}{133-78x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Solve $$x^5=\dfrac{133x-78}{133-78x}$$ We have $D:133-78x\ne0,x\ne\dfrac{133}{78}$. In $x\in D$ the given equation is equivalent to $$x^5(133-78x)=133x-78\\78x^6-133x^5+133x-78=0$$ As $x=0$ is not a solution, we can divide both sides by $x^3\ne0$ to get $$78x^3-133x^2+\dfrac{133}{x^2}-\dfrac{78}{x^3}=0\\78\left(x^3-\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)-133\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)=0$$ I am not able to come up with a subtle substitution. It would have been easier if we had $x^2\color{red}{+}\dfrac{1}{x^2}.$

$x=1$ is an "obvious" solution. What else? Thank you!

Comment: divide by $x-1/x$, substitute $t=x+1/x$

Comment: @user8268 Good idea. One could give the hint that $x^3-1/x^3=(x-1/x)(x^2+1+1/x^2)$

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h588715p3485359

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying to a common denominator gives
$$
0=78x^6 - 133x^5 + 133x - 78=(13x^2 + 6x + 13)(3x - 2)(2x - 3)(x + 1)(x - 1).
$$
The factorisation arises by the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Another obvious solution is $x=-1$. So we can write the equation as, $$(x^2-1)(78x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+78)=0$$ and comparing coefficients, we can easily find $a=c=-133$, $b=78$.

Now divide this (second polynomial) by $x^2$ and substitute $t=x+\frac1x$ to get a quadratic in $t$. It's easy to solve then.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x^3-\frac{1}{x^3})=\sum_{n=3}^3x^n-x^{-n}$

$(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})=\sum_{n=2}^2x^n-x^{-n}$

Then solve:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=3}^3x^n-x^{-n}=\frac{133}{78}\sum_{n=2}^2x^n-x^{-n}
\end{equation}

Computationally, that gives $x=-1, x=2/3, x=1, x=3/2$. Plus complex solutions.